# How to override two same trait method?

Tags: php, traits

Please read my code below

```
class A 
{
    public function echo($key)
    {
        if ($key === 1) return 'one';

        return 'default';
    }
}

trait X 
{
    public function echo ($key)
    {
        if ($key === 2) return 'two';

        return parent::echo($key);
    }
}

trait Y
{
    public function echo ($key)
    {
        if ($key === 3) return 'three';

        return parent::echo($key);
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    use X, Y {
        X::echo as echoX;
        Y::echo as echoY;   
    }

    public function echo ($key)
    {
        if ($this->echoX($key) !== parent::echo($key)) {
            return $this->echoX($key);
        }

        return $this->echoY($key);
    }
}

$object = new B();

echo $object->echo(2);
```

Look at method echo in class B
Is there anything that could simplify this behaviour ?

Note:
Currently there are only 2 traits that have same method,
If there are 10 traits that have same method, do I must use if else 9 times ?

Thank you

Comment: if you have 10 traits that have the same method it means you have wrongly designed code

Comment: You should better use hierarchy

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to fix with this code? It sounds like *maybe* you want some kind of decorator pattern, but it's hard to say what this is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your example code is pretty much nonsense. There's absolutely no reason why those should be in different traits (or even in different methods). Show us some _real_ example and we might be able to point out where the design is flawed.

Comment: Okay I will give a real example, I'm currently using Laravel with libraries and both used a method "getAttribute", this caused a conflict and I need to solve it by using the code above... Any other choice ?